# twitter bootstrap responsive customising div layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap's responsive style sheet and I have 4 squares in divs spanning 12 columns, so |3|3|3|3|

and when I view this in a mobile browser I see:

|12|

|12|

|12|

|12|

But I want to see:
|6|6|
|6|6|

In other words, I dont want the items to appear one after the other, more two on one row and two on the next.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default bootstrap's media query does the following:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
[class*="span"], .uneditable-input[class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
float: none;
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
```

In order to achieve the layout you need, set another media query something similar to :

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
[class*="span"], .uneditable-input[class*="span"], .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
float: left;
width: 50%;
}
```

Tweek the css as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned with `.span3` DIVs a media query like this will work..

```
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-fluid .span3 {
    width:44%;
    float:left;
  }
  .row-fluid .span3:nth-child(3) {
    margin-left:0;
  }
}
```

This would still allow the cols to switch to 100% width (stacked) at less that 400 pixels for tiny screens. Demo: http://bootply.com/69753

Another option is to use the responsive utility classes as shown in this demo:http://bootply.com/64868 ,but this requires separate markup for each responsive "view".